# ¿Cómo ejecutar una llamada después de una promesa en JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promesas

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación usando el API de Pokémon. La cosa es que para obtener las evoluciones debo conocer primero el `id` del pokémon antes de hacer la petición. Primero obtengo los datos generales mediante `$http` pero una vez que me se ejecuta la promesa quisiera ejecutar una función para obtener las evoluciones. El resultado es que me da error y no sé si esté usando mal mi sintáxis o es más cosa de lógica.

Dejo mi código y un ejemplo en JSFiddle.

```
angular.module('pokedexApp', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        var pokeurl = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/';
        var evolutionRequestUrl = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/';

        $scope.pokemonName = '';

        $scope.searchPokemon = function() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: pokeurl + 'pokemon/' + $scope.pokemonName
            }).then(function callback(response) {
                var id = responde.data.id;
                $scope.pokemon = response.data;

                // Getting evolutions
                var getEvolutions = function(id) {
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: evolutionRequestUrl + id;
                    }).then(function callback(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                };

                console.log(response);
            });
        };
    });
```

JSFiddle:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2vfd36q/)

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: `url: evolutionRequestUrl + id;` en esa línea no va punto y coma, quítalo

Comment: Creo que deberías echar un vistazo a http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#chaining y a http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/ para entender un poco mejor los patrones de las promesas y no continues usando los antipatrones descritos en la respuesta aceptada.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es bueno tener material para entender a fondo los patrones y las buenas prácticas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que no defines una funcion dentro del `then()` del http, sino que lo invocas directo

```
$scope.searchPokemon = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: pokeurl + 'pokemon/' + $scope.pokemonName
    }).then(function callback(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.pokemon = response.data;
        var id = responde.data.id;

        // Getting evolutions
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: evolutionRequestUrl + id;
        }).then(function callback(response){
            console.log(response);
        });

    });
};
```

veras que el `getEvolutions()` no es necesario, salvo si esa funcionalidad la defines separado, como ser

```
angular.module('pokedexApp', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);

function mainCtrl($scope, $http) {

    var pokeurl = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/';
    var evolutionRequestUrl = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/';

    $scope.pokemonName = '';

    $scope.searchPokemon = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: pokeurl + 'pokemon/' + $scope.pokemonName
        }).then(function callback(response) {
            var id = responde.data.id;
            $scope.pokemon = response.data;

            // Getting evolutions
            getEvolutions(id);

            console.log(response);
        });
    };

    function getEvolutions(id) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: evolutionRequestUrl + id;
        }).then(function callback(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
}
```

veras que la funcion esta por fuera del success del http, esta a nivel del controller

Comment: alguien podria indicar porque es una respuesta negativa? si ven algo incorrecto avisen asi podemos solucionarlo y aprender, con votar negativo sin decir nada no aportan para resolver el problema

Comment: Porque uno de proposito de las promesas es eliminar anidamiento. Tu respuesta hace exactamente eso, crear anidamiento por lo que se puede considerar un antipatrón.

Comment: entiendo que anidas las invocacions http realizando el return del promise, pense que solamente se queria invocar un http en el sucess y solo eso, aunque es verdad que tu implementacion queda mas prolija. No me quedo claroen el catch() cual de de las invocaciones http esta atrapado?  o quizas son ambas

Comment: Usar un solo `catch` es una de las razones por la que siempre se debe usar *encadenamiento* de lo contrario siempre tienes que especificar un `catch` para cada llamada o no especificarlo y crear mala arquitectura. En este caso el `catch` se ejecuta si alguna de las dos llamadas falla.

Comment: eso me gusto, no conocia el encadenamiento

Comment: Uno de los puntos claves de las promesas es que te permite crear un código que se asemeja a un `try...catch` pero asincrónico, es por esto que aunque `catch` es una palabra reservada de javascript usualmente se usa para nombrar el método que maneja flujo de error en las promesas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres lograr se conoce como *encadenamiento de promesas*, que es la forma en la que siempre debes estructurar el código cuando una promesa **dependa del resultado** de una promesa anterior.

[image: flujo de la promesa]

Básicamente una vez que una promesa termina retornas otra promesa que es manejada en otro método `.then`. Si te imaginas dos flujos de agua, uno al lado del otro, uno para los errores y el otro para el código de tu aplicación entienderás mejor como funciona este mecanismo.

```
promesa().then(function() {
    // Obtienes el id del pokemon
    // Retornas la llamada a las evoluciones
}).then(function() {
    // Haces algo con las evoluciones
});
```

Así es como debería quedar

```js
angular.module('pokedexApp', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var pokeurl = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/';
    var evolutionRequestUrl = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/';

    $scope.pokemonName = '';

    $scope.searchPokemon = function() {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: pokeurl + 'pokemon/' + $scope.pokemonName
      }).then(function callback(response) {
        var id = response.data.id;
        $scope.pokemon = response.data;

        // Con este resultado se construye la siguiente llamada
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: evolutionRequestUrl + id
        })
      }).then(function callback(response) {
        // Se maneja el resultado
        // Si otra llamada depende de este se retorna otra promesa
        console.log(response.data);
      }).catch(function() {
        // Puede haber mas de un catch 
        // pero siempre debe haber uno al final
        alert('Ocurrió un error');
      });
    };
  });
```

```css
input {
  min-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid 1px lightgrey;
  height: 24px;
}
button {
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid 1px lightgrey;
  height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="pokedexApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="pokemonName">
  <button type="button" ng-click="searchPokemon()">Buscar</button>
  <div ng-if="pokemon">
    <div style="width: 300px; float: left; text-align: center">
      <img ng-src="{{pokemon.sprites.front_default}}" style="width: 200px; height: 200px" alt="photo">
      <h1>{{pokemon.name}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>Stats</h4>
      <div ng-repeat="stat in pokemon.stats">
        <div>{{stat.stat.name}}: {{stat.base_stat}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```